# aiogram бот выключается через день

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот, python-telegram-bot

Запустил я бота на aiogram на хостинге pythonanywhere.com и через день он перестает работать, наверное это не из-за сервиса хостинга, наверное если бы запустил на своем ПК он бы тоже через 1-2 дня выключился бы. Помогите пожалуйста может проблема в executor'e

пытался загуглить и узнать, но не нашел ничего на аиограм

Answer (score 1):

На этот вопрос можно только гадать. Но могу вместе с вами предположить, что скорее всего это ограничения самого хостинга. Если вы используете бесплатный аккаунт, вам доступно *100 cpu-seconds*. Также предположу, что вы используете polling, а этот метод как раз может и тратить ваши доступные ресурсы cpu-seconds.
Чтобы точно убедится, что проблема не боте, сделайте логирование в файл - [cсылка на статью](https://habr.com/ru/companies/wunderfund/articles/683880/).

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename="py_log.log",filemode="w")
```

Comment: А что вы предлагаете использовать вместо polling'a,  бот на этом и работает как никак